# Filtering console output containing multiline strings in Xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode, multiline

I'm printing JSON data that spans multiple lines to the console. I'm prefixing all my messages with a tag and then filtering by that tag to keep things relevant. So my messages look like this with no filter:

```
TAG: {
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
... 
}
```

When I filter by TAG, I only see the first line because as far as I can tell, Xcode is just checking line by line instead checking by message.

```
TAG: {
```

How can I make Xcode output all the lines in the JSON? Is there a better way than writing my own print function that splits by `\n` and prefixes each line with TAG? This might not even work because the values might have a `\n` internally.

Comment: Xcode? Do you mean your swift or objective-c code?

Comment: I'm using swift, but I don't understand how it matters.

Comment: So the problem isn’t with your code but with Xcode itself?

Comment: I believe so. I've tried manually prefixing with `TAG` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.description` property while printing. 
Here is an example
`print(yourObject.description)`
It prints everything in one line and while doing a filter, you will be able to see everything.

This worked for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is better than nothing, but it isn't exactly what I wanted so I'll leave this question open for now.